# Lost password link is redirecting to /shop/my-account/lost-password/

Tags: password, reset

The “Lost your password?” link on the standard WordPress login screen (wp-login) links to /shop/my-account/lost-password/ instead of the WP standard (wp-login.php?action=lostpassword). My website is the following: www.lazonemph.com

I use Members plugin and Wocommerce..

1) How do I set this back to the WP password page? Because right now my user can't reset their password since the lost/password page is blocked by the members plugin. This link works fine: https://lazonemph.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

Can you help me with that please? 
Thank you!

Comment: you can change the link on the login page with this fliter : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_url

Comment: I tried that filter and it has not effect on the 'Forgot your password'-URL on the login-screen. I'm in the same situation. One could argue that this is a WooCommerce-question, since it's related to that and therefore off-topic. I would argue that it is a WordPress-question, to be able to spot which filter can change the URL of the 'Lost Password'-link.

Answer (score 2):

Please Add Below Code To Your Active theme's functions.php file:

```
remove_filter('lostpassword_url', 'wc_lostpassword_url', 10, 1);
function wdm_lostpassword_url() {
  return site_url( '/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword' );
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'wdm_lostpassword_url', 10, 0 );
```

Or Try in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /shop/my-account/lost-password/ /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword
```

Or Else you can also do with Cloudflare, If you're using it

Hope this helps you...

Comment: That doesn't do anything. 
What's extra-wierd is that if I write `die()` inside my functions.php-file, then the login-page loads and renders as it should (so hooks written in there doesn't affect the login-page). Something tells me that this has to be done in a file or something.

Comment: @Zeth I have edited the My Answer

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Remove `lost-password` under Woocommerce >> Advanced >> Account Endpoints.

Remember to clear your cache, if you have that enabled.

---

**Comment**

[The solution found in this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/334762/128304)

As I wrote in the comment, then nothing happend, when I added stuff to my `functions.php`-file and reloaded the login-page. So I'm not sure what is with all those 'add_filter`-functions, which is to be found all over the place.