# WooCommerce changes lost password reset link

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password, reset

When I activate WooCommerce plugin, the lost your password does not work and can't sent password reset email to users. But when I deactivate WooCommerce, the lost your password link at login page starts working.
Is it possible to not use WooCommerce link because it is not working and changes the reset link.

Answer (score 4):

I hope think this may work.

Insert this code into php file or php insert plugin, WooCommerce will no longer change password reset link.

```
function reset_pass_url() {
    $siteURL = get_option('siteurl');
    return "{$siteURL}/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword";
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'reset_pass_url', 11, 0 );
```

Comment: for those wondering where to add this code I found that adding after line 42 in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-account-functions.php did the trick. Guess it's a woo commerce bug

Comment: You shouldn't change the plugin code. You'll lose it every update. This code should be added to the functions.php of your theme.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to do this without code, open the WordPress admin and then click "WooCommerce", "Settings", "Advanced". Under "Account Endpoints", delete "lost-password" from the "Lost password" field.

Comment: I had to clear my cache after doing this, but it worked.

Comment: Cool! This is the perfect solution for this problem, Thank you so much for saving my hours.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to add this to your theme's functions.php file:

```
remove_filter('lostpassword_url', 'wc_lostpassword_url', 10, 1);
```

This removes the modification added by WooCommerce.