# Lost password link redirects to my-account/lost-password/,how to fix it back to default lost password

Tags: password

My lost password option in the wp login page redirect to woocommerce lost password page.How to set it back to the standard wp lost password option.?I want it to redirect to "wp-login.php?action=lostpassword".
I am using,woocommerce,paid membership pro,buddypress plugins.
I found this [Lost password link is redirecting to /shop/my-account/lost-password/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/290858/158576), but I couldn't understand it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put below code into your theme **functions.php** file

```
remove_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'wc_lostpassword_url', 10 );
```

OR

```
function reset_pass_url() {
    $siteURL = get_option('siteurl');
    return "{$siteURL}/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword";
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'reset_pass_url', 10, 2 );
```

Please let me know if any query.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: If this answer is usefull for you then please mark as a accepted answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without code by going to the WooCommerce administration, Settings, Advanced, and removing the "lost-password" text from the Lost password field under Account Endpoints:
[image: arrow pointing to lost password field]

Comment: this worked for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the filter that WooCommerce uses to replace the lost password URL like so:

```
remove_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'wc_lostpassword_url', 10 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
function wdm_lostpassword_url() {
  return site_url( '/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword' );
}
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url', 'wdm_lostpassword_url', 10, 0 );
```

Add it to to your current active theme's functions.php file